# Emailing password on sign up

Tags: php, security, passwords

Is it a horrible idea to email users their password on sign up - before it's hashed by the server side code and stored into the DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's user-entered, yes, it's a bad idea. E-mail is unencrypted and can be intercepted in transit between your mail server and theirs, as well as potentially being readable by folks with access to the two servers.

If it's a one-time temporary password, the risk is smaller, as they should change it shortly afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I'd email them a temp password, then require them to change in upon first login. Granted someone could change it before the user got the chance.

Comment: good idea. You could check the IP. If it's not the same on the activation as it was on signup, there might be something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Better not, because if users specify an incorrect email address, other people can login using their information.

Also, you can make it more secure by not allowing to reset your password if you didn't login at least one time with the password that was used for the registration.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer depends on how secure you think your credentials need to be.  If you're a bank or any other site that deals with PII, then it's absolutely a terrible idea.  But if you don't think there's a real payoff in cracking your site, then you can use your own discretion.  It's definitely not a good idea from a security standpoint, but if there are organizational factors such as budget or legacy code that may drive you into such a corner, then you can consider it.

Also, I agree wholeheartedly with the other folks who answered suggesting not to send a user their password if they've picked it.  That's an unnecessary potential security hole!

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is this.

**Option 1** - if user picks his password, don't mail it.

**Option 2** - if you generate a password, send to user, have a link to active his account and change password.

Depends for what users get registered, each option can be used.